# Method is not called inside of another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I am trying to make an object named *Dialogo*. The idea is create it some functions and then call them inside of another method itself. Take a look:

```
function Dialogo(tamano){
    this.tamano = tamano;

    this.cerrar = function(){
        $('#dialogo_fondo').remove();
    };

    this.mostrar = function(){
        var dialogo_fondo = $('<div>').attr({id: 'dialogo_fondo' });
        $('body').fadeIn("slow", function(){$(this).append(dialogo_fondo);});
        $('#dialogo_fondo').css( {"width": $(window).width(), "height": $(window).height()});
        $('#dialogo_fondo').click(function(){ 
            this.cerrar(); 
        });
    };  
}
```

Using jquery 1.7.2. According to the code, when I do click over **#dialogo_fondo** element, it should be removed, because the **cerrar()** method was triggered in click event. But it does not work. Can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in `mostrar` declaration points to the anonymous function instance, check it with `console.log(this);`. So you need to create another reference to outer object `var that = this;` and use it instead:

```
function Dialogo(tamano){
    var that = this; // <--- here is the magic

    this.tamano = tamano;

    this.cerrar = function(){
        $('#dialogo_fondo').remove();
    };

    this.mostrar = function(){
        var dialogo_fondo = $('<div>').attr({id: 'dialogo_fondo' });
        $('body').fadeIn("slow", function(){$(this).append(dialogo_fondo);});
        $('#dialogo_fondo').css( {"width": $(window).width(), "height": $(window).height()});
        $('#dialogo_fondo').click(function(){ 
            that.cerrar(); // <---- use "that", not "this"
        });
    };  
}
```

Comment: You are like Harry Potter.. applying the magic! Thank you so much!

Comment: @manix: I hope you got the idea of why your previous solution didn't work

Comment: yes, I am really newbie in js, but I got it! There are some tricks like this that I need to keep in mind in futher

Comment: Jquery's $.proxy() is also useful for cases like this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/